# Jquery mobile refresh, loading icon not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.5. The refresh is done using `window.location.reload();` function and earlier the icon was working fine. Now, I had use the loading function somewhere else in the code like this:

```
$.mobile.loading("show", {
    text: "loading more..",
    textVisible: true
});
```

The icon didn't show so I added `ajax-loader.gif` in the `/css/images` folder and this function started to work.

Unfortunately the earlier icon that was automatically called for reload() is not showing the gif anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend just not using any gif at all... In this case it might worth it to take a look at jQuery's plugin [jRoll](https://fitsbach.github.io/jRoll) or a similar plugin or just make your own spinner (Loading icon) using pure CSS, SVG without the use of a gif.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it.